# Html.fromHtml not working for span

Tags: android, colors, textview, html

I have a `TextView` and I want to show multi-colored text in that. I am using `html.fromHtml` for this, but it is not showing any color.

My code is:

```
//statusToShow is a String
Log.d("html ==>", statusToShow) ;
RStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(statusToShow),
TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Value from Log is:

`<span style='background-color:#80B5FF;color:#fff'>C</span> <span style='background-color:#CF8DEA;color:#fff'>P</span> <span style='background-color:red;color:#fff'>E</span> <span style='background-color:green;color:#fff'>D</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Spannable` like this:

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Text To Span");

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 4,
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

This will make the background color of `Text` Blue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Not all tags are supported, list of supported tags is here: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html